# ampersand entities in long strings make template malfunction

Tags: xml, string, xslt, chunking

I'm using a template I found on the internet to split long strings into chunks. It seems to work fine with most text but if there is an entity in this supposedly long text input such as '&' it makes the output chunk too long.

My consumer of this data needs long description values in certain entities broken down into fixed length pieces. So this data is fine:

```
<tag>
    <text>This is a long string 1This is a long string 2This is a long string 3This is a long string 4</text>
</tag>
```

resulting output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>
    <text>
      <text>This is a long string 1</text>
      <text>This is a long string 2</text>
      <text>This is a long string 3</text>
      <text>This is a long string 4</text>
   </text>
</tag>
```

this data is too long here in the first output string:

```
<tag>
    <text>&amp;This is a long string 1This is a long string 2This is a long string 3This is a long string 4</text>
</tag>
```

resulting output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>
    <text>
      <text>&amp;This is a long string </text>
      <text>1This is a long string </text>
      <text>2This is a long string </text>
      <text>3This is a long string </text>
      <text>4</text>
   </text>
</tag>
```

I tried changing the output to html but that didn't change the behavior - anyways the output is supposed to by xml.

I'm actually not sure if the problem is really solvable as the XML is only the middle man and the actual source and destination ultimately are plain text database field, but I'd like to chunk the long string into short strings exactly the desired length.

Here is the template.. here the desired size is: 23

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" exclude-result-prefixes="max">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="pChunkSize" select="23" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text/text()" name="chunk">
<xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

<xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
<text>
<xsl:value-of select=
   "substring($pText, 1, $pChunkSize)"/>
</text>
<xsl:call-template name="chunk">
<xsl:with-param name="pText"
    select="substring($pText, $pChunkSize+1)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have seen some discussion about this and it might be intractable - since chopping & in the middle (if it was towards the end of the segment) results in invalid XML.

Comment: `&amp;` is a symbol representing a single character and is counted as such when calculating the length of a string. The length of the string in `<text>&amp;This is a long string </text>` is exactly 23 characters. When the string is delivered to its final destination and unescaped for human consumption, it will look like this:`"&This is a long string "`.

Comment: i see the extra requirement of segmenting long strings into "arrays" of short strings seems to be the problem. if the &amp; falls on a boundary the XML isn't valid anymore. i still have to find some reasonably solution that probably isn't technical-

Comment: I am afraid I still don't see the problem you are trying to solve. As i said, the `&amp;` is a single character. The code you are using will never split it.

Comment: the expansion gets dumped into the output (which is XML) causing the elemnr to have a value longer than sllowed

Comment: We seem to be going in a circle. The element does NOT have a value longer than allowed. If you want to use XML, you must accept the XML rules. In XML, `&amp;` is part of the **markup**; the content is the ampersand character. If you count the characters of the entity name, why don't you also count the characters in the start `<text>` and end `</text>` tags? It makes just as much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly divided the text into four pieces each of length 23 characters, and have correctly represented each of those 23-character strings in its proper XML representation.

If they can't handle it, it must be because they aren't processing the XML correctly using a conformant XML parser, so the problem is at their end, not at yours.

Comment: thanks- it is the design of the receiving system that makes the problem- the representation is not fitting into the length limited outputstring